# Dialing phone number from Windows Gadget

Tags: c#, javascript

I'm calling JavaScript function from my Gadget application to dial phone number.

C# code:

```
HtmlPage.Window.Invoke("CallPhone", string.Format("callto://{0}", Number));
```

Java script code:

```
function CallPhone(Number) {
wnd = window.open(Number);
```

}

The function is working well but it opening internet explorer window, i do not know JavaScrip and in a first glance didn't  found any other solution.
So is there better solution that allow to dial number wihout opening browser window.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The **callto://** link format will always start your default internet browser, so it's up to it if it will open a new window or not.

Is this supposed to start Skype?

Ok, simply start the skype.exe prpcess with the callto argument.

Comment: Yep. It suppose to start Skype.